# How can I tell if local powershell is enabled/disabled from the registry on Windows 2008 R2?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2008-r2

I was wondering if someone could help. I'm looking for the registry key indicting if powershell is enabled or disabled.

I checked the keys and values in `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\PowerShell`, but didn't see any difference between enabled and disabled states.

Where else could it be ?

Comment: `reg query HKLM\Software /v ExecutionPolicy /s`

Comment: Thanks Josef,  but it doesn't provide the enabled status.  It returns execution policy for 'ScriptedDiagnostics', always reported as "Unrestricted" whether it is enabled or disabled

Comment: What do you mean by "enabled"?

Comment: Enabled means the feature is installed and can used and work correctly.  Look at the W2K8 server manager Features. Just because the feature is disabled it not completely uninstalled. For example, the registry entries are intact.

Comment: PowerShell is installed by default on Server 2008 R2. What do you mean by "can be used and works correctly"? Are you talking about execution policy or something else?

Comment: Well Powershell does not come installed in these servers, there is a rigid lockdown policy on all utilities installed. Execution policy is a group of privileges, different than enabled/disabled.

Comment: How about `WMIC PATH Win32_OptionalFeature | find /I "WindowsPowershellRoot"`

Comment: How about Get-WindowsFeature ? (OptionalFeture mentioned above exists only on desktop)

Comment: I can't use WMIC. I'm trying to access the state in a WIX installer. The only way to extract data is via the registry.

Comment: Then you need to define very clearly and very explicitly what you consider as "can be used and works correctly" for PowerShell. Or take a different approach entirely. I seem to recall from when I dabbled with WiX that it supported running C# code snippets.

Comment: Thanks Ansgar.. I figured out you cannot get there without vbScript, Jscript or a custom dll to call WMIC :(